# How can I center a node in react d3 tree without clicking on the node

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

Can we center a center a react d3 tree by using an external button ?
[React D3 tree](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/rd3t-demo-jkhqs?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A607%2C23)

I have manage to extract x and y cordinates of that node. And I translate the container by width/2+x, and height/2+y, it translates but its kind of janky and doesnt achieve the purpose. It changes all the time and eventually slides the container to extreme right.

My main purpose is that I want to center a node when an external button is clicked. I studied the code example there they just set dimention of the container. I didn't understand how setting dimention would center a node.

```
        <Tree
          dimensions={dimentions}
          data={data}
          scaleExtent={{ max: 10, min: 0.3 }}
          pathFunc={stepPathFunc}
          pathClassFunc={customPathClass}
          nodeSize={nodeSize}
          translate={translate}
          orientation="vertical"
          enableLegacyTransitions
          renderCustomNodeElement={(rd3tProps: any) =>
            renderForeignObjectNode({ ...rd3tProps, foreignObjectProps })
          }
        />
```

I have setup tree like this and center tree at first like this

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (containerRef.current && once) {
      const { width, height } = containerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
      setDimentions({ height, width });
      setTranslate({ x: width / 2, y: height / 10 });
      setOnce(false);
    }
  });
```

```
  const handleCenterUser = () => {
    const user = document.getElementById("isuser");
    if (user && containerRef.current) {
      const { x, y } = user.getBoundingClientRect();
      const { height, width } = containerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    }
  };
```

I want to center tree when this function executes. I have set id of the node that i want to center with isuser. when I inspect it has id with `isuser`. Everything is working but I am stuck here.